# Is read operation in ConcurrentHashMap reliable regarding the return value?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I read in a book that read in `ConcurrentHashmap` does not guarantee the most recently updated state and it can sometimes gives the closer value. Is this correct?

I have read its javadocs and many blogs which seems to say otherwise (i.e. it is accurate).

Which one is true?

Comment: How do you plan to read the data?

Comment: Then you shouldn't worry, it will return the most accurate value.

Comment: Is there any other way which might not give me accurate value?

Comment: see also the package javadoc - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Comment: Do you refer to HashMap or CuncurrentHashMap (there is a space in the title)

Comment: Please write the names of classes as they are, don't separate them in terms because it causes confusion for readers.

Comment: Which book? Without knowing, we can not tell whether there is a fault in the book or a fault in your comprehension of the book.

Answer (score 1):

From [`ConcurrentHashMap` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

One point to highlight is that an `Iterator` is not going to reflect changes that are made after the `Iterator` is created. So if you need to iterate over the values of the map, while other threads are adding to the map, and you care about the most current state of the map, then using a `ConcurrentHashMap` may not be the implementation of map that you need.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up. It looks way better!

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedMap` seems to synchronize **all** accesses. Why that design choice in `ConcurrentHashMap` ?

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, a ConcurrentHashMap should behave like a set of volatile variables; map keys being the variable addresses. `get(key)` and `put(key, value)` should behave like volatile read and write.

That is not explicitly stated in the document. However, I would strongly believe that it is the case. Otherwise there will be a lot of unexpected, surprising behaviors that undermine application logic.
I don't think Doug Lea would do that to us. To be sure, someone please ask him on `concurrency-interest` mailing list.

Suppose it does obey the volatile semantics, we can reason based on Java Memory Model -

All volatile reads and writes form a single total order. This can be considered a pseudo time line, where reads/writes are points on it.

A volatile read sees the immediate preceding volatile write, and sees only that write. "Preceding" here is according to the pseudo time line.

The pseudo time line can differ from "real" time line. However, in theory, a volatile write cannot be infinitely postponed on the pseudo time line. And, in pracitce, two time lines are pretty close.

Therefore, we can be pretty sure that, a volatile write should become visible "very quickly" to reads.

Comment: ... `volatile` variables...  Actually, it _is_ stated in the `ConcurrentHashMap` API contract, but not in those words.  The Javadoc says, "...an update operation for a given key bears a _happens-before_ relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key."  That's basically the same as how `volatile` is described in the JLS:  An update to a `volatile` field establishes _happens-before_ with any subsequent read of the same field.

Comment: @jameslarge - yes, but that is only part of the volatile semantics. we also need `synchronization-order`, and [synchronization-order consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.7)

Comment: maybe a better question is, are `ConcurrentHashMap` operations *sequentially consistent". I guess it must be; or at least, people assume it for granted.

Answer (score 0):

That is the nature of concurrency. Any concurrent collection may give you the old value in a field if a currently pending write operation is not safely finished. That is in all cases what you have to expect. The collections made for concurrency will not give you corrupted values or break if you access them from multiple threads, but they may give you old values, if writing is not done.

Comment: If the value is not overwritten, then it's not an old value, it's the current one... Surely it does not give you the future value, which is normal

Comment: Yes. But with concurrency it is possible to read a value *while* it is written. The "normal" collections do something undefined if that happens. The concurrent collections give you the old value or block until writing is done.

Comment: You can't look at `Collections.SynchronizedCollection` for that. This is a simple low performance blocking wrapper around a normal collection. Have a look at the ConcurrentHashMap implementation.

Comment: Hmm ok, then I think your answer should make it clear that it is only due to the implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` and not with the nature of all concurrent collections